# GTK4 + brew + m2

Tags: command-line, homebrew

I am having a lot of problems trying to run code made with GTK4 previously made on an intel Mac. I made the code in pure C using GTk4 for a gui. I needed to configure my path back on those days and did the same here.

I ran the next commands after brew was installed:

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> ~/.zprofile
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

And even I added the next line to my .zshrc file.

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Then I run my code as in the old days, using:

```
gcc hellow.c -o helloworld `pkg-config gtk4 --cflags pkg-config gtk4 --libs`
```

And I get the same error:

```
hellow.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
```

I know is because my system can't find the library, something is still missing in my configuration I suppose. But made several changes and still nothing. What could be happening here?.

Comment: What is the output of `pkg-config gtk4 --cflags pkg-config gtk4 --libs`?  Does it match your system configuration? Also, "made several changes" doesn't usually give us a lot of information about what you did :-)

Comment: Sorry@nohillside for the made several changes and not put the output, my mistake. At the end the problem was: pkg-config was not installed at all in the first place U.u

Comment: I know that you've solved the problem already, but future visitors might benefit from seeing some analysis done. Also, I wonder why you didn't get a `pkg-config: command not found` error when running `gcc` as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, OMG I just had to install pkg-config. I feel so dumb, all those steps do not work If I don't do:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Then using the command:

```
gcc hellow.c -o helloworld `pkg-config gtk4 --cflags pkg-config gtk4 --libs`
```

Works as a charm to run the GTK+C code...